# Data migration tool installation getting killed in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, installation, data-migration

I am trying to install a data migration tool in Magento 2.3.3. But it gets killed in between

```
./composer.json has been updated
 Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  Killed
```

What can be the reason?
I tried through composer as well as GitHub

Comment: add -vvv at end of your command and check the error.

Comment: I have successfully installed the tool using these two commands composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool ,
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.3

Comment: @KishorThummar i tried this commands, but got killed in between

Comment: add -vvv at end of your command and check the error.

Comment: It  does not show any error. It shows killed only agian